# Inject httpcontext into custom attribute outside controller in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, custom-attributes, httpcontext, filterattribute

I need to inject httpcontext into custom attribute that is used outside the controller. I found several solutions how to do it in controller, but my case is little tricky. Now I have following code in my PermissionController

```
[PermissionFilter(PermissionEnum.Permission, AccessLevelEnum.Create)] <-- it works perfectly
[HttpPost("users/{userId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> 
  AssignPermissionToUser([FromBody] List<PermissionToVM> permissions, int userId)
{
    await _permissionService.Assign(permissions); <-- .Assign() extension
    //code goes here
}
```

In the method above there is a call of extension method `.Assign`. This method code is available below.

```
//[SecondPermissionFilter(PermissionEnum.Permission,
   AccessLevelEnum.Create)] <-- here I check permissions but don't 
   know how to inject the httpcontext
public async Task Assign(List<PermissionToVM> permissions)
{
    //code goes here
}
```

As mentioned in many websites I visited f.e. here https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/05/accessing-httpcontext-asp-net-core/ injecting of httpcontext outside the controller can be done using IHttpContextAccessor. The problem is that I don't know how to use it without passing it into constructor. My custom attribute should be called as decorator `[SecondPermissionFilter(PermissionEnum.Permission, AccessLevelEnum.Create)]` when only permission settings should be passed, so there is no any reference to httpcontextaccessor.

Is this even possible? If not, there is maybe another way to do this?

EDIT: Here is the code of `SecondPermissionFilter` class:

```
public sealed class SecondPermissionFilterAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly PermissionEnum _requestedPermission;
    private readonly IEnumerable<AccessLevelEnum> _accessLevelCollection;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor; //<-- how to inject?

    public PermissionFilterAttribute(PermissionEnum requestedPermission, params AccessLevelEnum[] accessLevelCollection)
    {
        _requestedPermission = requestedPermission;
        _accessLevelCollection = accessLevelCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd better show us the definition of your custom attribute. That's where you can inject the IHttpContextAccessor.

Comment: @Bellash controller permission attribute works and I would like not modify it. Mentioned in code 'SecondPermissionFilter' is fairly simple. I added definition in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is something called `Property Injection`. As per the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-service-container-replacement) this is not something that is supported out of the box by the .NET Core DI Container.

You can however use a third party library such as [Ninject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-service-container-replacement) or [Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html#property-injection) - both of which are available via NuGet.

In my opinion the Ninject syntax is nicer, *however* as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38459987/5209435), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39582784/5209435) property injection itself is considered bad practice. So if possible I would try to avoid it.

So you should instead use one of the three methods specified by the filter [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#dependency-injection), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725674/5209435) breaks things down a bit more.

**Edit**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4102176/5209435) deals specificically with Attribute injection, the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029723/5209435) looks to achieve this without external dependencies.

Comment: I know how to do this inside the controller, I need to get httpContext inside custom attribute outside the controller. Links you provided are for controllers. But your explanation why I should not do this i enough for me to voteup. Thanks

Comment: Apologies, I've edited my answer to include some links to attribute specific cases.